# Where do I put this conditional comment for a gradient background on IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, gradient

Ok I have been searching for hours and have found answers but none that seem to work for me. I am trying to use a gradient background that I generated on colorzilla.com. Below is my code. To "complete" the ie 9 support colorzilla says: Support for full multi-stop gradients with IE9 (using SVG).

Add a "gradient" class to all your elements that have a gradient, and add the following override to your HTML to complete the IE9 support:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .gradient {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

But I cannot for the life of me figure out where to put the comment or where I should be putting the "gradient" class

I have to have this turned in tomorrow morning (AH!) please help!

code (without the comment):

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv=Content-Type>
<STYLE type=text/css>HTML {
    TEXT-ALIGN: center; FONT-FAMILY: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background: #0067ad; /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #0067ad 0%, #2688d1 52%, #61a1cc 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#0067ad), color-stop(52%,#2688d1), color-stop(100%,#61a1cc)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #0067ad 0%,#2688d1 52%,#61a1cc 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #0067ad 0%,#2688d1 52%,#61a1cc 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #0067ad 0%,#2688d1 52%,#61a1cc 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(top,  #0067ad 0%,#2688d1 52%,#61a1cc 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0067ad', endColorstr='#61a1cc',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
 COLOR: #666666; FONT-SIZE: 18px
}
BODY {
    TEXT-ALIGN: center; FONT-FAMILY: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; COLOR: #fffde7; FONT-SIZE: 18px
}
#content {
    TEXT-ALIGN: justify; MARGIN: 0px auto; WIDTH: 720px
}
IMG {
    BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px; BORDER-TOP: 0px; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px
}
</STYLE>

<META name=GENERATOR content="MSHTML 8.00.6001.18975"></HEAD>
<BODY>
<p><IMG alt=" Transcender IT Certification Success" 
src="http://www.transcender.com/images/logo.png" width=268 height=64></p>
<p><img src="http://www.transcender.com/images/downpostit.png" alt="Transcender will be right back" width="284" height="280"><BR>
  <BR>
</p>
<DIV id=content>
  <p>Sorry for the inconvenience, but the Transcender website will be 
    unavailable Saturday, April 21st for routine 
    maintenance. Please come back and visit us again on Sunday, April 22nd and get 
    10% off your next order*. Use promo code: <B>MANDOWN12</B>.  <br>
    <br>
    *Offer expires 4/23/12, excludes cd &amp; voucher purchase option
<BR>
    <BR>
    <BR><BR>
  </p>
</DIV></BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're applying the gradient to the `HTML` tag, so you'd use this for your conditional block:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
    html {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

And you'd place it after the  block in the code you listed above (between `</style>` and `<meta>`).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You would place the code inside of your `<head>` tags like so.

```
<head>
    <!--[if gte IE 9]>
      <style type="text/css">
        .gradient {
           filter: none;
        }
      </style>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```